# Adding double quotes to beginning, end and around comma's in bash variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a shell script that accepts a parameter that is comma delimited,

```
-s 1234,1244,1567
```

That is passed to a curl PUT json field.  Json needs the values in a `"1234","1244","1567"` format.

Currently, I am passing the parameter with the quotes already in it:
`-s "\"1234\",\"1244\",\"1567\""`, which works, but the users are complaining that its too much typing and hard to do.  So I'd like to just take a comma delimited list like I had at the top and programmatically stick the quotes in.

Basically, I want a parameter to be passed in as 1234,2345 and end up as a variable that is `"1234","2345"`

I've come to read that easiest approach here is to use sed, but I'm really not familiar with it and all of my efforts are failing.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in BASH:

```
$> arg='1234,1244,1567'

$> echo "\"${arg//,/\",\"}\""
"1234","1244","1567"
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS='","' -v q='"' '{$1=$1; print q $0 q}' <<< "1234,1244,1567"

"1234","1244","1567"
```

or shorter with `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/[^,]+/"&"/g' <<< "1234,1244,1567"

"1234","1244","1567"
```

translating this back to `awk`

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/([^,]+)/,"\"\\1\"","g")}' <<< "1234,1244,1567"

"1234","1244","1567"
```

Comment: Clever use of awk's line-rewrite. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
echo QV=$(echo 1234,2345,56788 | sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' -e 's/,/","/g')
```

result:

```
echo $QV
"1234","2345","56788"
```

just add double quotes at start, end, and replace commas with quote/comma/quote globally.

Answer (score 1):

easy to do with `sed`

```
$ echo '1234,1244,1567' | sed 's/[0-9]*/"\0"/g'
"1234","1244","1567"
```

- `[0-9]*` zero more consecutive digits, since `*` is greedy it will try to match as many as possible
- `"\0"` double quote the matched pattern, entire match is by default saved in `\0`
- `g` global flag, to replace all such patterns

In case, `\0` isn't recognized in some `sed` versions, use `&` instead:

```
$ echo '1234,1244,1567' | sed 's/[0-9]*/"&"/g'
"1234","1244","1567"
```

Similar solution with `perl`

```
$ echo '1234,1244,1567' | perl -pe 's/\d+/"$&"/g'
"1234","1244","1567"
```

**Note:** Using `*` instead of `+` with `perl` will give

```
$ echo '1234,1244,1567' | perl -pe 's/\d*/"$&"/g'
"1234""","1244""","1567"""
""$
```

I think this difference between `sed` and `perl` is similar to this question: [GNU sed, ^ and $ with | when first/last character matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808332/gnu-sed-and-with-when-first-last-character-matches)

Comment: The `\0` isn't working for me, and results in each value being `0`. Are you sure you don't mean `&`?

Comment: I tried in a recent OS X, FreeBSD 10.3, and a Busybox installation whose `sed --version` reports `This is not GNU sed 4.0`. Also tested on GNU sed 4.2.1 where it worked. Looks to me as if `\0` might be specific to GNU,  I think I'd go with `sed -r 's/[0-9]+/"&"/g'`.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Great that you're keeping portability in mind. I found that busybox's sed supported `-r` but not `-E`, which is why I suggested that. Since FreeBSD added `-r` for compatibility, I no longer have any systems that do not support `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo 1234,1244,1567 | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)/\"\1\"/g'
"1234","1244","1567"
```

ie. replace all strings of numbers with the same strings of numbers quoted using backreferencing (`\1`).